# How to override date_select when hidden from view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use javascript to juggle between `ongoing` and `oneshot` challenges. If a user clicks on `ongoing` for example then I want the `:deadline` to be `nil`, but instead the `:deadline` is still defaulted to today despite the javascript hiding the `:deadline` from view.

```
<%= form_for(@challenge, html: { data: { modal: true } })  do |f| %>

  <% Challenge::CATEGORY.each do |c| %>&nbsp;
    <%= label(c, c) %>
    <%= f.radio_button(:category, c, :class => "date-format-switcher", checked: (c=='One-Shot')) %>
  <% end %>

  <div id='id_of_first_div'>
    <%= f.date_select :deadline, :order => [:month, :day, :year] %>
  </div>
  <div id='id_of_second_div'>
    <%= f.date_select :date_started, :order => [:month, :day, :year] %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#id_of_second_div').hide()
    $('#challenge_category_one-shot').click(function(){ $('#id_of_first_div').show(); $('#id_of_second_div').hide(); });
    $('#challenge_category_ongoing').click(function(){ $('#id_of_first_div').hide(); $('#id_of_second_div').show(); });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean that the value sent from the `deadline` input is still the days date? - you would need to either remove the input from the form or set is value to "". Just hiding a input does not change what is sent when the form is posted.

Comment: You can also set the `disabled` attribute - the client does not send those inputs. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html

Comment: Yea @max I want to disable `:deadline` somehow when the user switches out of the `oneshot` category and into `ongoing` and I want to disable `date_started` when the user switches the other way.

Comment: "Just hiding a input does not change what is sent when the form is posted" - @Max. I guess that's my question. There's no way to stop a hidden input from sending?

Answer (score 0):

Form inputs with the `disabled` attribute are not sent by the client:

```
$(function(){
   $('#id_of_second_div').hide();
   $('#challenge_category_one-shot').click(function(){ 
      $('#id_of_first_div').show().attr('disabled', false); 
      $('#id_of_second_div').hide().attr('disabled', true); 
   });
   $('#challenge_category_ongoing').click(function(){
     $('#id_of_first_div').hide().attr('disabled', false); 
     $('#id_of_second_div').show().attr('disabled', true);
   });
});
```